# Apple Notification Center - From the web

Tags: javascript, macos, push-notification, notificationcenter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mountain Lion Notification Center from Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667718/mountain-lion-notification-center-from-safari)

So I am having an issue finding out good information about how Apple's push notification system works with web apps.  I know that you can register your application with their service, but then how does it work after that?

With the release of Mountain Lion very soon, I think it will become important to be able to directly integrate with push notifications from a webapp.  Can anyone point to any documentation outlining this?

Comment: I do not think this topic can be discussed publicly yet, since the Mountain Lion APNS is still in private beta.

Comment: Dang, I was hoping to get a jump start on this...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667718/mountain-lion-notification-center-from-safari) might help you.

Comment: @enovav that is more of a html5 approach that requires the site to stay opened, I believe the OP is looking for push notification support for webapps. I could be wrong.