# Mountain Lion Notification Center from Safari

Tags: javascript, osx-mountain-lion

Is it possible to use something similar to the alert() function to send notifications to notification center using javascript? I tried googling but it just brings up the apple website for 10.8 features. Any pointers to how this could be done would be awesome, if it's even possible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, its possible to send notifications to notification center using HTML5. Check this out http://dangercove.github.com/html5-notifications/

Comment: Can anyone confirm that Safari 6 does in fact support this part of HTML5 and display these notifications in the Notification Center? (here's hoping... and hoping that it also works the same way on iOS 6 when it arrives).

Comment: @Colin'tHart I can confirm. Tested before posting this answer

Comment: @Colin'tHart I don't think it would work with iOS, as safari and web apps don't really run in the background, so how would they send a push notification? I guess if you wanted to send them when your website was in view, but I think it's kind of odd to do that when you could just do the same on your web page. Of course, I might be wrong and it works when safari is in the background.

Comment: I tested with Mobile Safari on iOS 6.0 through Web Inspector, but `window.Notification` returns `undefined`.

Comment: It would be amazing if stackoverflow could incorporate this option. Wouldn't it be nice to receive notifications about current posts and answers / comments to questions or participated discussions?